# How to store in a JavaScript variable the selected rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, django

Let's say we have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th class="active">
              <input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" />
          </th>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for gene_variant in gene_variant_results %}
      <tr>
          <td class="active">
              <input id="selectedGene" type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item"/>
          </td>
          <td>{{ gene_variant.67 }}</td>
          <td> {{ gene_variant.72 }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="select-all" class="btn btn-primary">Select all</button>
<button type="submit" id="show-selected" class="btn btn-primary">Show selected</button>
```

And let's say that gene_variant_results has for example, 4 results. Each result corresponds to a row (each row has about 100 columns, in this example I only put 11 for illustrative purposes):

```
(1290, 'chr10', '73498294', '73498294', 'C', 'G', 'exonic', 'CDH23', 'DM', 'CM127233', 'DFNB12)
(1291, 'chr11', '73498295', '73498295', 'D', 'H', 'exonic', 'CDH24', 'DM', 'CM127234', 'DFNB13)
(1292, 'chr12', '73498296', '73498296', 'E', 'I', 'exonic', 'CDH25', 'DM', 'CM127235', 'DFNB14)
(1293, 'chr13', '73498297', '73498297', 'F', 'J', 'exonic', 'CDH26', 'DM', 'CM127236', 'DFNB15)
```

For example, if I click on the first two checkboxes and then click on the `#show-selected` button, I would like to store in a JavaScript variable the values of those selected rows. (The full `gene_variant` content, not just the `selected <td>` values)

Some illustrative semi pseudo-code of what I want:

```
$( "#show-selected" ).click(function() {
    var selected_checkboxes = //get the full content of each selected row and store it in an array of strings or any other data structure
});
```

Comment: use data attribute ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes ? linked ref to a full json information....

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MisterJojo, will take a look!

Comment: You can also add json information directly on any DOM elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your `show selected` button is clicked first loop through `checked` checkboxes then use `$(this).closest("tr")` to get closest tr  then loop through whole trs childrens(td) and push value inside some array using  `.push()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("button#show-selected").click(function() {
  var outer_array = []
  //loop through checked checkboxes
  $("tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index, item) {
    var inner_array = []
    var selector = $(this).closest("tr") //get closest tr
    //loop through trs td not first one
    selector.find("td:not(:first)").each(function() {
      inner_array.push($.isNumeric($(this).text().trim()) ? parseInt($(this).text().trim()) : $(this).text().trim()) //push in inner array
    })
    outer_array.push(inner_array) //push in outer array
  })
  console.log(outer_array)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="active">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" />
      </th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" />
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td> 2</td>
      <td> abcdsre</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="active">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" />
      </td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td> 22</td>
      <td> abcde</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="select-all" class="btn btn-primary">Select all</button>
<button type="submit" id="show-selected" class="btn btn-primary">Show selected</button>
```

Comment: It works but it's setting everything to strings. For example the arrays would become like: `("1290", "chr10", "73498294", "73498294", "C", "G", "exonic", "CDH23", "DM", "CM127233", "DFNB12")`

Answer (score 0):

By using [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)  for linking ref to a full json information....

```js
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('#parent_div')

const info = 
  [ [ 1290, 'chr10', '73498294', '73498294', 'C', 'G', 'exonic', 'CDH23', 'DM', 'CM127233', 'DFNB12' ]
  , [ 1291, 'chr11', '73498295', '73498295', 'D', 'H', 'exonic', 'CDH24', 'DM', 'CM127234', 'DFNB13' ]
  , [ 1292, 'chr12', '73498296', '73498296', 'E', 'I', 'exonic', 'CDH25', 'DM', 'CM127235', 'DFNB14' ]
  , [ 1293, 'chr13', '73498297', '73498297', 'F', 'J', 'exonic', 'CDH26', 'DM', 'CM127236', 'DFNB15' ]
  ]

parentDiv.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('div.infoDiv')) return

  console.clear()
  console.log('info =',...info[target.dataset.ref])
  }
```

```css
.infoDiv { margin:.5em; cursor:pointer; }
.infoDiv:hover { background-color: greenyellow; }
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <div class="infoDiv" data-ref="0">click me 0</div>
  <div class="infoDiv" data-ref="1">click me 1</div>
  <div class="infoDiv" data-ref="2">click me 2</div>
  <div class="infoDiv" data-ref="3">click me 3</div>
</div>
```

You can also add json information directly on any DOM elements

```js
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('#parent_div')

const info = 
  [ [ 1290, 'chr10', '73498294', '73498294', 'C', 'G', 'exonic', 'CDH23', 'DM', 'CM127233', 'DFNB12' ]
  , [ 1291, 'chr11', '73498295', '73498295', 'D', 'H', 'exonic', 'CDH24', 'DM', 'CM127234', 'DFNB13' ]
  , [ 1292, 'chr12', '73498296', '73498296', 'E', 'I', 'exonic', 'CDH25', 'DM', 'CM127235', 'DFNB14' ]
  , [ 1293, 'chr13', '73498297', '73498297', 'F', 'J', 'exonic', 'CDH26', 'DM', 'CM127236', 'DFNB15' ]
  ]

info.forEach((el,i) =>
  {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.className   = 'infoDiv'
  div.textContent = `click me ${i}`  
  div.info        = el
  parentDiv.appendChild(div) 
  })
parentDiv.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('div.infoDiv')) return
  console.clear()
  console.log('info =',...target.info)
  }
```

```css
.infoDiv { margin:.5em; cursor:pointer; }
.infoDiv:hover { background-color: greenyellow; }
```

```html
<div id="parent_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the time you have dedicated to it, but it is not what I need.

In your answer, you are defining some constants in JavaScript, the truth is that I need to pass that data from each selected `gene_variant` to JavaScript. I can't hardcode it.

In your answer I don't see how I can send the data from gene_variant to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the checkbox for each row then just store the index of the clicked row in an array.

When you click the #show-selected button then you can refer back to the main data store and fetch the data associated with that metric.  In this way your actual datasource will be the single point of truth and you don't have to maintain duplicate copies in the selected_list & the main data source

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, could you provide some illustrative code?

Comment: @Cheknov  here is a minimal example.  You can see the selected items in the console:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-nncqea?file=index.js